# Poststep archiveArtifacts: how to retrieve files from other machine?

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, artifacts

I run a Jenkins pipeline which executes jobs on a (always the same) virtual machine using `agent.jar`.

These jobs produce artifacts on the `VM-workspace` directory and these files are successfully transferred to Jenkins.

Now I want the pipeline to retrieve data from that `VM-workspace` too.
How can I configure the "`archiveArtifacts` to access my VM?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:
In the job config activate "Permission to Copy Artifact"  "Projects to allow copy artifacts" : *

In the job config, Post build actions, Archive the artifacts, Files to archive: result.html

In the pipeline script:

```
  stage("foo-stage") {
            steps {
                script {
                    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE', catchInterruptions: false) {
                        timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                            String jobName = "foo-job"
                            String artifactsFilter = "*.html"
                            result = build job: jobName
                            copyArtifacts filter: artifactsFilter, projectName: jobName , selector: specific("${result.number}")
                            archiveArtifacts artifacts: artifactsFilter
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```